# UITableViewCell with image text alignment

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm kinda new to iOS development, so forgive me if this is basic (which I'm sure it is!).

I've created a `UITableView` with 3 rows and 1 column, and the middle of the 3 cells needs to have an image in it's `imageView`:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favouriteicon.png"];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Favourites";
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

The problem I have is that, even though I'm trying to centre the text, it is knocked along to the right by the width of the image. I don't understand what else I have to do, and I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using other     UITableViewCellStyle's

you can go through some of the samples in apple's site

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Listings/4_TableViewCellSubviews_Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-4_TableViewCellSubviews_Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_27

Comment: I've tried the other three styles and they each seem to disable the effectiveness of 

`cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;`